Differences in symbol export between gcc and msvc for implictely define constructors
I have a class Bar which holds a vector of a non-copyable class Foo:
struct  Foo {
    Foo(int &a) : m_a(a){}
    int &m_a;
};

struct CORE_EXPORT Bar {
    std::vector<Foo> f;
};

When I compile this code with GCC with -fvisibility=hidden and marking Bar as visibility default, it compiles fine.
However, when I compile this same code with MSVC, marking Bar with __declspec(dllexport), I get a compilation error due to deleted Foo::operator=.
I understand this is happening because under the hood, MSVC is generating a copy constructor for Bar and exporting it, which results in trying to use a copy constructor for Foo.
If I don't mark Bar as __declspec(dllexport), the code compiles fine.
Here is a complete example in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/hshddaz5z
Why is this behavior different? Which implicitly defined symbols does MSVC export that GCC doesn't?

I can't say why dllexport has the behavior of instantiating all member functions, but if you are just looking for a workaround: The problem only occurs because the copy assignment of std::vector always exists and is non-deleted, even if the element type is non-copyable and an instantiation would be ill-formed. That's necessary to permit std::vector<T> to work with incomplete T. As a consequence the copy assignment of Bar is also not implicitly deleted. So it looks like it should be instantiated as well and instantiation fails. You can delete Bar's copy assignment manually.

If std::vector<> copy ctor always exists, I guess when I dont dllexport, the compiler doesn't really instantiate that constructor as it's not used, and everything works fine. When dllexporting, the compiler don't know what a user of the library will do, so needs to instantiate the copy ctor of Bar, which leds to the issue. But doesn't really explain why works in GCC

The copy assignment operator is implicitly inline. It doesn't need to be exported. Every translation unit can generate it if needed and they are all guaranteed to be equivalent. So the question is rather why dllexport is designed to still force generating the definition for these member functions.
